# How to set values of a renderscript globalusing rsSetElementAt_type() function

Tags: renderscript, android-renderscript

In Android RenderScript:

A kernel may not have more than one input or one output Allocation. If more than one input or output is required, those objects should be bound to rs_allocation script globals and accessed from a kernel or invokable function via `rsGetElementAt_type()` or `rsSetElementAt_type()`.

Now I knew that the function `rsGetElementAt_type()` takes three parameters :

```
rs_allocation input , uint32_t x and uint 32_t y
```

but I do not know how to set values of a global rsSetElementAt_type()

Can Anyone please tell me what parameters this function take and in which order?

I have searched android documentation and google but could not find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type contained in the `Allocation`, but you can find details [Renderscript Runtime API Reference page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/reference/rs_allocation_data.html#android_rs:rsSetElementAt).